# Why model is always coming null even though view is persent

Tags: spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value="/sign",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getSign(final ModelMap map){

        ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("abc");
        return model;
    }
```

whenever debugger is coming to model its returning model always as a null and no error also.

Comment: what were you expecting to see there? Normally on a GET request you 'set' the form model and on the POST request you 'receive' the populated model

Comment: i want to display the jsp page on get call but nothing is coming.

Comment: what do you mean 'nothing is coming'. 404 page or empty data or something else? Please help us with more details for us to be able to help you

Comment: i am getting page not found error.